# How to display Messagebox with Retry option in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing

Scenario:

1. Pickup some data from an Excel file.
2. Search for it in a Text file.
3. If the data is not found, display a popup message box with a 'Retry' option.
4. User opens the Excel file and changes the value.
5. Click the 'Retry' button.
6. The Line which threw the error earlier should get executed again.

I need to know, how to display a message box with  a 'Retry' option, clicking on which shall execute the line of code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the code that pops up the box in a loop and continue the loop if the retry button was clicked. The response code from the jOptionPane tells you what button was popped.

Comment: Let me try to implement that and share the results. Thank You.

Comment: @avalancha The problem with posting source code blind (especially when the OP hasn't posted their code) is you don't know if it is actually helpful to what they are doing. The generic answer is better in this case as otherwise my assumptions as to what they are doing could break the result.

Comment: @VelGanesh See how you get on. If you get stuck edit the question with your code as you wrote it and put a comment on here so I see it. I'll take a look for you.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. Certainly this might be the case in more specific examples but here we know it's java and from what you write it shouldn't be more than `boolean going = true; while (going) { going = getOptionPaneResult(); }` That's all I was asking for and you seem to have the knowledge to put ***getOptionPane()*** correctly, I don't, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

this will give you an option pane with 4 buttons java C++ VB COBOL

```
String[] choices = {"Java", "C++", "<acronym title="vBulletin">VB</acronym>", "COBOL"};
int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                               null                    
                             , "Which is your favourite programming language?"    
                             , "Language Poll"            
                             , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION 
                             , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
                             , null                    
                             , choices                   
                             , "None of your business"  
                           );
```